# Question on proving Subsets and Cartesian products

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let A, B, C, and D be subsets of a universal set U.

(a) Prove that (A\B)\C ⊆ A\(B\C). Find and prove a necessary and sufficient condition for equality to hold.

(b) Prove that (A × C) ∪ (B × D) ⊂ (A ∪ B) × (C ∪ D).

Comment: Typo? What does $A(B\setminus C)$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we prove that

$\color{blue}{1.}\quad(A\setminus B)\setminus C=A\setminus(B\cup C)\;$,

$\color{blue}{2.}\quad A\setminus(B\setminus C)=\left[A\setminus(B\cup C)\right]\cup(A\cap C)\;$.

**Proof of 1.**

If $\;x\in(A\setminus B)\setminus C\;,\;$ then $\;x\in A\setminus B\;$ and $\;x\notin C\;,\;$ hence

$x\in A\;,\;x\notin B\;,\;x\notin C\;,\;$ consequently $\;x\in A\setminus(B\cup C)\;.$

Moreover, if $\;x\in A\setminus(B\cup C)\;,\;$ then $\;x\in A\;,\;x\notin B\cup C\;,$

hence $\;x\in A\;,\;x\notin B\;,\;x\notin C\;,\;$ consequently

$x\in(A\setminus B)\setminus C\;.$

**Proof of 2.**

If $\;x\in A\setminus(B\setminus C)\;,\;$ then $\;x\in A\;$ and $\;x\notin B\setminus C\;.$

There are two possibilities: $\;x\notin C\;\text{ or }\;x\in C\;.$

$x\notin C\;,\;x\notin B\setminus C\implies x\notin B\cup C\implies x\in A\setminus(B\cup C).$

$x\in C\implies x\in A\cap C\;.$

In any case $\;x\in\left[A\setminus(B\cup C)\right]\cup(A\cap C)\;$.

Moreover, if $\;x\in\left[A\setminus(B\cup C)\right]\cup(A\cap C)\;,\;$ there are two possibilities: $\;x\in A\setminus(B\cup C)\;$ or $\;x\in A\cap C\;.$

$x\in A\setminus(B\cup C)\implies x\in A\;,\;x\notin B\implies\\\implies x\in A\;,\;x\notin B\setminus C\implies x\in A\setminus(B\setminus C)\;.$

$x\in A\cap C\implies x\in A\;,\;x\notin B\setminus C\implies x\in A\setminus(B\setminus C).$

In any case $\;x\in A\setminus(B\setminus C)\;$.

---

Now we prove that

$\color{blue}{3.}\quad(A\setminus B)\setminus C\subseteq A\setminus(B\setminus C)\;$.

$\color{blue}{4.}\quad(A\setminus B)\setminus C=A\setminus(B\setminus C)\iff A\cap C=\emptyset\;.$

**Proof of 3.**

From $\color{blue}{1}$ and $\color{blue}{2}$, it follows that

$(A\setminus B)\setminus C=A\setminus(B\cup C)\subseteq\left[A\setminus(B\cup C)\right]\cup(A\cap C)=\\\qquad\qquad\;\;=A\setminus(B\setminus C)\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

**Proof of 4.**

If $\;(A\setminus B)\setminus C=A\setminus(B\setminus C)\;,\;$ then, from $(*)$, it follows that

$A\setminus(B\cup C)=\left[A\setminus(B\cup C)\right]\cup(A\cap C)\;,\;$ hence

$A\cap C\subseteq A\setminus(B\cup C)\;,\;$ consequently

$A\cap C=\emptyset\;$,

indeed, if there existed an element $\;x\in A\cap C\;,\;$ then $\;x\;$ would be in $\;A\setminus(B\cup C)\;,\;$ therefore $\;x\;$ would not be in $\;C\;,\;$ but it is impossible since $\;x\in A\cap C\;.$

Moreover, if $\;A\cap C=\emptyset\;,\;$ from $\color{blue}{1}$ and $\color{blue}{2}$, it follows that

$(A\setminus B)\setminus C=A\setminus(B\cup C)=\left[A\setminus(B\cup C)\right]\cup(A\cap C)=\\\qquad\qquad\;\;=A\setminus(B\setminus C)\;.$